# Why mathieu function in scipy not periodic?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, gsl

I found Mathieu function in scipy.special is not periodic. Here is the code and plot:

```
import scipy.special as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,10*np.pi,100)
plt.plot(x,sp.mathieu_cem(3,3,x)[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

However in Mathematica, it is clearly periodic:

```
Plot[MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[3, 3], 3, x], {x, 0, 10 Pi}]
```

Are the two function's not the same? Since the docs of scipy don't have much detail, I don't know how to obtain the periodic version of `ce`.

By the way, in `gsl` there are [similar functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Angular-Mathieu-Functions.html#Angular-Mathieu-Functions), what's the relation with scipy? Are they the same one?

[image]

#### Edit

After converting to degrees, I found there are more cycles in scipy than in mathematica, any explanations?

[image]

Comment: SciPy's `scipy.special.mathieu_cem` takes `x` in degrees.

Comment: re: edit. You did not convert to degrees correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy.special.mathieu_cem` takes `x` in degrees. This output looks about right for the Python code going up to 31.4 degrees and the Mathematica code going up to 31.4 radians.

Comment: To convert from radians to degrees, multiply by (180/π).  In your updated code in the question, you didn't divide by π.